# Error: Formula result is data type (Date), incompatible with expected data type (Date/Time)

Tags: apex, workflow, field-update

I'm developing a work flow on Case and I have the following conditions

**Rule Name** : Escalate Based on Keywords in Subject or Description

**Criteria** :

```
Contains(LOWER( Subject ),"urgent") || 
Contains(LOWER( Subject ),"password") || 
Contains(LOWER( Subject ),"down") || 
Contains(LOWER( Subject ),"emergency") || 
Contains(LOWER( Subject ),"internal server error") || 
Contains(LOWER( Description ),"urgent") || 
Contains(LOWER( Description ),"password") || 
Contains(LOWER( Description ),"down") || 
Contains(LOWER( Description ),"emergency") || 
Contains(LOWER( Description ),"internal server error")
```

**Immediate Actions:**

```
Field Update: Set Priority to Service Affecting
Field Update: Set Support Level to Tier 3
Field Update: Set Target Resolution Date to TODAY()
```

I have created `"Target Resolution Date"` as Date/Time and trying to set the value for the **DATEVALUE("YYYY-MM-DD")** and **DATEVALUE("YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss")** doesn't works.

[image]

and I am getting below error:

[image]

Comment: change datevalue to date? --> https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=formula_using_date_datetime.htm&type=0

Comment: please try to use DATETIMEVALUE instead of DateValue . Example DATETIMEVALUE("2005-11-15 17:00:00")

Comment: Did you try changing functions? read the documentation, google the error?

Comment: `YYY-MM-DD` is the format...you're supposed to substitute in actual numbers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to use `NOW()` as a formula for your field update

> Description:  Returns a date/time representing the current moment.

https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=customize_functions_i_z.htm&type=0&language=en_US

Comment: Just asking from curiosity perspective, now() + 30 would give result with Date/Time.. right ?

Comment: @user4567570 yes.  NOW() +5 calculates the date and time five days ahead of now

Comment: Perhaps `TODAY()` would be more appropriate.